# How to prove a cipher resistant to differential cryptanalysis?

Tags: cryptanalysis, algorithm-design, differential-analysis

How do you prove that a cipher is resistant to differential cryptanalysis? It's said that Rijndael has been proven resistance to differential cryptanalysis. How do cryptographers do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I apply differential cryptanalysis to a block cipher?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27/how-do-i-apply-differential-cryptanalysis-to-a-block-cipher)

Comment: Why is this a duplicate? The other is a question about how to _apply_ differential cryptanalysis, and this question is about _proving a function resistant_ to differential cryptanalysis.

Comment: the keyword being 'possible' duplicate.

Comment: rath, you can add `possible` to any sentence and you can make it valid. So I think you are being a big harsh here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The design documents for Rijndael explain exactly how the designers proved its resistance to differential cryptanalysis.

Read [their submission to the AES competition process](http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf#page=1), particularly Section 8.2 and the Annex.  To understand their approach, it will probably help to understand differential cryptanalysis and read some of the related literature.  You can find a more detailed explanation in their book, [The Design of Rijndael: AES](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540425802).

You might enjoy the following research papers:

- [The Wide Trail Design Strategy](https://encrypted.google.com/url?q=http://www.researchgate.net/publication/225704500_The_Wide_Trail_Design_Strategy/file/d912f50c0517f24d78.pdf&sa=U&ei=J0TkUZr5NqerigLcmYHADw&ved=0CBcQFjAA&sig2=X0i5W-YYGU6QU_v8eBGMYw&usg=AFQjCNHcY0-OlXQ_mS6i5RaCPjKPWct-Kg)
- [Provable Security against Differential and Linear
  Cryptanalysis for the SPN Structure](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.132.5403&rep=rep1&type=pdf)